# Convert (number | number[]) to number[]

Tags: javascript, typescript

It might be simple question, but I have not figured out as I am still newbie in TypeScript, I have a variable:

```
let v1: number | number[];
```

I want to convert

```
let v2: number[];
```

If v1 = 1 => v2 will be [1]

if v1= [1, 2] => v2 will be [1,2]

Comment: Where do you want this conversion to take place? Can you provide a sample for the use case?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I have reactive multi select in Angular that input can be either number or array of number, but inside the component I only keep internal field as number[] to simplify the process and work well in reactive form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Test if the variable is an array, create one if not:

```
const v2 = Array.isArray(v1) ? v1 : [v1];
```

Comment: perfect, thanks alot

Answer (score 2):

##### Slightly more compact method (fully immutable)

Accepted answer seems to have minor *side effect* (when `v1` is array, `v2` will inherit reference to `v1`):

```
const v1: number | number[] = [1, 2]
const v2: number[] = Array.isArray(v1) ? v1 : [v1] // v1: [1, 2], v2: [1, 2]

v1.push(3) // v1: [1, 2, 3], v2: [1, 2, 3]
```

I may suggest my solution (simply use [`Array.prototype.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)):

```
let v1: number | number[]
let v2: number[]

v1 = 1

v2 = Array().concat(v1) // v2: [1]

v1 = [1, 2]

v2 = Array().concat(v1) // v2: [1, 2]
```